# "Entrar" ainda aparece mesmo depois do usuário estar logado (React)

Tags: javascript, react

Eu gostaria de ajuda para criar esse código, quero que o "entrar" saia depois do usuário ter feito login.
Seguinte, antes do usuário fazer o login, aparece la a opção "Entrar". O que acontece é que quando o usuário faz o login o span "Entrar" continua aparecendo e eu queria esconder ele quando o usuário fizesse o login mas não sei como começar.

```js
const AccountMenu = React.lazy(() => import('@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/AccountMenu'));

/**
 * The AccountTrigger component is the call to action in the site header
 * that toggles the AccountMenu dropdown.
 *
 * @param {Object} props
 * @param {Object} props.classes - CSS classes to override element styles.
 */
const AccountTrigger = props => {
    const talonProps = useAccountTrigger();
    const {
        accountMenuIsOpen,
        accountMenuRef,
        accountMenuTriggerRef,
        setAccountMenuIsOpen,
        handleTriggerClick
    } = talonProps;

    const classes = useStyle(defaultClasses, props.classes);
    const rootClassName = accountMenuIsOpen ? classes.root_open : classes.root;
    const { formatMessage } = useIntl();
    const [{ isSignedIn }] = useUserContext();

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <AccountTriggerContainer>
                <div className={rootClassName} ref={accountMenuTriggerRef}>
                    <button
                        aria-label={formatMessage({
                            id: 'accountTrigger.ariaLabel',
                            defaultMessage: 'Toggle My Account Menu'
                        })}
                        className={`${classes.trigger} trigger-action`}
                        onClick={handleTriggerClick}
                        data-cy="AccountTrigger-trigger"
                    >
                        <AccountChip
                            fallbackText={formatMessage({
                                id: 'accountTrigger.buttonFallback',
                                defaultMessage: 'Bem vindo(a)'
                            })}
                            shouldIndicateLoading={true}
                        />
                        <span className='signin'>
                            Entrar
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <Suspense fallback={null}>
                    <AccountMenu
                        ref={accountMenuRef}
                        accountMenuIsOpen={accountMenuIsOpen}
                        setAccountMenuIsOpen={setAccountMenuIsOpen}
                    />
                </Suspense>
            </AccountTriggerContainer>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default AccountTrigger;

AccountTrigger.propTypes = {
    classes: shape({
        root: string,
        root_open: string,
        trigger: string
    })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode fazer algo similar a este exemplo:

```
const AccountTrigger = props => {
    let successLogin = false
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <AccountTriggerContainer>
                <div className={rootClassName} ref={accountMenuTriggerRef}>
                    <button
                        aria-label={formatMessage({
                            id: 'accountTrigger.ariaLabel',
                            defaultMessage: 'Toggle My Account Menu'
                        })}
                        className={`${classes.trigger} trigger-action`}
                        onClick={handleTriggerClick}
                        data-cy="AccountTrigger-trigger"
                    >
                        <AccountChip
                            fallbackText={formatMessage({
                                id: 'accountTrigger.buttonFallback',
                                defaultMessage: 'Bem vindo(a)'
                            })}
                            shouldIndicateLoading={true}
                        />
                        {
                            !successLogin &&
                            <span className='signin'>
                                Entrar
                            </span>
                        }
                    </button>
                </div>
                <Suspense fallback={null}>
                    <AccountMenu
                        ref={accountMenuRef}
                        accountMenuIsOpen={accountMenuIsOpen}
                        setAccountMenuIsOpen={setAccountMenuIsOpen}
                    />
                </Suspense>
            </AccountTriggerContainer>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

sucessLogin sendo a variável que indica se o login foi bem sucedido ou não.